# How do i validate user input in a list C#

Tags: c#, validation, input

Am a newbie in C#. I have have created a list **players** with 2 radio button options for two teams.

Am able to add user input to the list but cant check if a name already exists in the list. Am using code below:

```cs
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
  namespace teamVal
         {
             public partial class Form1 : Form
              {
                   List<String> teams;
                  public Form1()
                  {
                      InitializeComponent();
                       // Create lists
                       teams = new List<String> { };
                   }

        private void btn_Submit2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string newteamname = txt_TeamName.Text.Trim();
            if (newteamname.Length == 0) return;

            if (teams.Contains(newteamname))
            {
                lbl_TeamStatus.Text = newteamname + " already exists";
                return;
            }
            
            if (rdo_Team1.Checked == true && (newteamname.Length > 0))

            {
                teams.Add(newteamname + ", Team 1");
                lst_Teams.DataSource = null;
                lst_Teams.DataSource = teams;
            }
            else if (rdo_Team2.Checked == true && (newteamname.Length > 0))
            {
                teams.Add(newteamname + ", Team 2");
                lst_Teams.DataSource = null;
                lst_Teams.DataSource = teams;
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_TeamStatus.Text = "You must check a team box";
                return;
            }
            txt_TeamName.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question to fix the format - and check the _preview_ before posting. also: 
welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: From your code example it looks like you are appending ", Team 1" or ", Team 2" to the team name and then inserting this into the team list. Your check for whether a team exists in the list does not take this append into account. I would suggest storing which team they are as a different variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `if` condition is wrong:

```
if (teams.Contains(newteamname)){ }
```

It can be as follows:

```
if (teams?.Where(x => x.Contains(newteamname)).Any() == true){ }
```

You are also appending the radio button text to string and then adding it to the list, which is why your condition is not working.

Comment: Genius ! That worked. I couldnt have figured that out in a million years.